# $\liminf_{n\to \infty}(P_{n+1} -P_n)>\liminf_{n\to \infty}(P_{n+1}) -\limsup_{n\to \infty}(P_n) =(n+1)\log(n+1)-n\log n>\lim_{n\to\infty}\log n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I saw a paper by Zhang Yitang that $\liminf_{n\to \infty}(P_{n+1}-P_n)<70000000$, where $P_n$ is the $n$th prime.

But by prime number theorem, $\liminf_{n\to \infty}(P_{n+1} -P_n)>\liminf_{n\to \infty}(P_{n+1}) -\limsup_{n\to \infty}(P_n) =\lim_{n\to\infty}((n+1)\log(n+1)-n\log n)>\lim_{n\to\infty}\log n$ for sufficiently large $n$. Then how can it be less than $70000000$?

Can anyone correct me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\liminf P_n = \infty,$ and $\limsup P_n = \infty$, since there are inifinitely many primes. So, the lower bound expression you've written is of the indeterminate $\infty - \infty$ form, which should give you pause.

The prime number theorem (PNT) says (in one version) that $\lim P_n/(n \log n) = 1.$ In other words, $P_n = n \log n + \mathrm{error}_n$, where $\lim \frac{\mathrm{error}_n}{n \log n} = 0,$ i.e., the error grows slower than $n \log n$. But this error term can be large in and of itself: even under the Riemann hypothesis, we only expect to be able to control $\mathrm{error}_n$ to (roughly) the scale $\sqrt{n}$. This is waaay larger than $(n+1) \log (n+1) - n \log n < 1 + \log n.$ This means that while the PNT is an accurate description of where the $n$th prime is, it cannot say anything about the gaps between consecutive primes, beyond speaking about them on average. But of course such an average is a very different kind of thing than a $\liminf$, which is tracking the minimum, in a way.